# Bypass Review Limit on Stack Overflow

Tags: bug, status-completed, review

Today while carrying out reviews on Stack Overflow, I noticed that a user had made 23 late answer reviews. I know that the limit is 20 so I wondered how they had bypassed the limit.

After a few moments, I discovered the method they used.

The bypass of the limit is done by making use of multiple browser tabs. You simply open new tabs for every review left in the queue (skipping the review in a new tab if you have it open in another tab) and then carry out the reviews once they are all opened.

I think this should be fixed.

Comment: Not the end of the world but I agree that server side validation should be added when making the review itself, not just when getting an item to review.

Comment: Also note that the review limit is dynamic, not static, and is based on the number of items in the queue.  This may not be the case here, but when the team changes the filters for the queue and effectively "adds" lots of items, you'll see people doing more reviews for a period of time.

Comment: Good to know @Servy. I don't think that it happened in this case though as they was only one user exceeding the 20 review limit today (until I exceeded it to determine how they did it).

Comment: As a new reviewer (5 days), I often cross-check a review I did against those of others. So I think (a) most reviews are are much too generous (not helped by the _limited_ options SO gives) and so, (b) somebody cheating by an extra three reviews will have little or no effect on SO, and (c) it could be inadvertent (I hate browser tabs, but most people love them).

Comment: I don't get this.  You are expected to be a responsible SO user when you review.  Even if you do know about the loop-hole, why on Earth would you abuse it?  That's just complete counter to what the system entrusts you with.  Feel free to consider that it might be a built-in way to test your responsibility, they've built that in from the get-go.

Comment: I'm just pointing out that this can be done. I'm not advocating it or anything @UphillLuge ;) I was thinking about this more last night and would I be correct in assuming that this applies to more of the StackExchange sites than just StackOverflow?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is fixed now. It should no longer be possible to exceed the daily *reviews per user per queue per day* limit. Bear in mind that extenuating circumstances exist, e.g. moderators can review more, and we allow more reviews per day when a queue suddenly spikes up in size.

Comment: Can we review just *more* or *as much as we want*?