# Daily review limit for Late Answers & First Posts *really* exceeded

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, new-users, late-answers

I know it's possible to [exceed the review limit for suggested edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158335/daily-review-limit-exceeded) but I was wondering how can this be possible for other queues, like Late Answers or First Posts?

Except the fact that a queue can suddenly spikes up in size, then everyone can reach the limit.

Since few days, [one guy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1410342/sfah) **always** reached the 20 limit per day, sometimes by 1 or 2, so I guess *it can happend* for someone, but today [it's 37](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/stats) :o

[image]

Does the [same problem from early november](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/153684/bypass-review-limit-on-stack-overflow) come back (ie: open multiple tab to got more review) or is it a new one ?

---

**Edit:**

**Problem #1**

Thanks to Daniel Fischer, I've found a *new way* to cheat the system. You can review a post twice by made a modification and hit <kbd>Done</kbd> and also hitting <kbd>No action needed</kbd>.

How to reproduce:

- open twice the review page (when you are on `review/first-posts/XXXXX`)
- on one tab, make a modification and hit <kbd>Done</kbd>
- on the other tab, just hit <kbd>No action needed</kbd>

You'll review the post twice. [As I did for this one](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/1256655).

**Problem #2**

If you open multiple tabs for multiple reviews you can review all posts twice and then reach more than 20: 40 if you're good. Using the same trick:

- make a change
- hit <kbd>Done</kbd>
- hit <kbd>No action needed</kbd> for the other tab

I did it for the last one, and [I'm now at 21](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/stats).

Comment: That user reviews the same items twice often, e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/1252769), but just look at the activities tab. It may be the system, but that doesn't seem right.

Comment: This sounds like it's another opportunity to ban people from review. I imagine it'll be fairly difficult to combat but extremely easy to detect...

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards Yes. That should totally lead to a longish review ban. Unless the review queue code is severely borked, that's clear evidence of cheating. (<jk>Sorry, j0k, no exemptions for science.</jk>)

Comment: @animuson why [new-users] instead of [first-posts]? This is not for new-users since the one that mostly cheats is an *established user*.

Comment: @j0k: You're reviewing first posts, which *come from* new users. Hence the tag. It is also stated clearly in the [meta-tag:review] tag wiki to use the [meta-tag:new-users] tag when referring to specifically the First Posts review task.

Comment: @animuson okay thanks, didn't know that.

Comment: This "exploit" will be fixed in our next build.

Comment: @Emmett Great !

Comment: Wow, people really will do *anything* to get a badge...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sorry - my bug :)  There was a case where multiple browsers could be left open to several different reviews all of which could be completed to exceed the max. It's fixed now.

I blame the hat over my eyes.

Comment: Are you sure the problem is solved ? [Just tried](http://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/1282619) and I still can review an item twice.